# What is the difference between must have been and had to have been?

Tags: grammar

I have gone through the answers but it couldn't satisfy me my doubt is still same that using had to have been is wrong and instead one should use must have been.

Answer (score -1):

Use 'must have' when expressing a personal opinion in the past, and use 'had to' when expressing an obligation in the past.

**OPINION:**

> It *must* have been great.

**OBLIGATION:**

> I *had to* wash my car yesterday .

From https://speakspeak.com/resources/english-grammar-rules/modal-verbs/must-have-to :

> The modal verb must has two past tense forms: had to and must have. Which form we use depends on whether we want to express obligation or if we want to say how certain we are about the probability of something happening.
> [image: Examples]

Comment: Do you really think, in the example exchange “I went to an end-of-pandemic party.” “Oh, it had to have been great!”, that “had to” represents some type of obligation?